# Is this graph 3-colorable?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-colorings, coding-theory

Consider the permutations of $0,1,1,2,2,3,3.$ Each permutation is corresponding to a vertex in graph $G$. So, the graph $G$ has $630$ vertices.

Each vertex has exactly 6 neighbors. $P$ is connected $Q$ if $P$ can be obtained from $Q$ by swapping 0 with another element. For example,
0112233 is connected to 1012233, 1102233, 2110233, 2112033, 3112203, 3112230.

Question: What is the chromatic number of graph $G?$ Is $G$ 3-colorable?

---

What we've proved: $G$ is not a perfect graph.
It has many odd holes with length $\geq 11$.

Comment: The chromatic number is at most $4$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I constructed the graph correctly, according to a program the chromatic
number is $4$, so the graph is not 3 colorable.

The program is:
https://code.google.com/p/graphcol/

Got the same result after converting the problem to SAT
and ran certified UNSAT solver.

The proof for unsatisfiability was only about 11MB.

The computation took few minutes and the 4-coloring was found
very fast.

The graph was constructed with sage program:

```
def graphperm123():
    S=Permutations([0,1,1,2,2,3,3])
    E=[]

    for u in S:
        u=list(u)
        i=u.index(0)
        for j in xrange(len(u)):
            if j==i:  continue
            v=u[:]
            a=v[j]
            v[j]=0
            v[i]=a
            E += [(tuple(u),tuple(v))]
    G=Graph(E,multiedges=False,loops=False)
    return G
```

Comment: Sage can compute the chromatic number...

Comment: @IgorRivin I know this, but I gave up sage after reasonable for me time. How long does it take in sage? And do you use `.chromatic_number()` or `first_coloring(3)`?

Comment: Look at the documentation of chromatic_numer() or coloring(), and you will see that different "solver" are available inside.

Comment: @NathannCohen OK, I looked. What is the best wall clock time to show it is on 3-colorable in sage you have? Do you get a certificate like the certified UNSAT?

Comment: It took 361 seconds on my computer (with CPLEX installed, and algorithm='milp') to prove that the chromatic number is 4, and have the coloring. No certificate that it is not 3-colorable, however (though it was proved that it is not 3-colorable)

Comment: @NathannCohen Assuming correctness of my implementation of 3-coloring to SAT, certificate for UNSAT of 3-coloring using one of Knuth's solvers was obtained in less that 8 seconds and the proof is about 11MB. 4-coloring was found roughly in the same time. Observe that I have **certificate**, assuming correctness of the implementation. This is on one core on an old machine.

Comment: @NathannCohen Is CPLEX free of charge? I see only trial versions.

Comment: It is indeed much faster. Would be a nide addition to Sage if you have the time. About CPLEX, it is indeed proprietary but there is something called the "academic initiative" which means that if you can be associated to some reasearch activity/center then you can use it for free.

Comment: P.S.: Actually Sage can solve SAT instances once Cryptominisat is installed. Maybe it would just amount to translate model the problem as SAT and see what happens.

Comment: @NathannCohen Old version of cryptominisat showed 3-coloring is UNSAT in 6.4 seconds without proof. 4-coloring was found in 0.055 seconds. The reduction to SAT (CNF) is straightforward, essentially the same as to ILP, with two more loops per vertex up to the colors to ensure exactly one color.

Comment: Sounds good. Would you be willing to patch Sage?